How to find TabItem by name?
I'm building a simple browser in WebView2 and I'm trying to add page titles to tabs. I've made the script to get the page title and tab name, just now I can't set the title itself.
Here's the script for sending the data to the main window with tabs. The text variable is the tab name.
public void UpdateTab(string text)
{
    MainWindow mainwindow = ((MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow);
    mainwindow.UpdateTabName(webView.CoreWebView2.DocumentTitle, text);
}

EDIT: Full code: (the strings can be in Polish)
MainWindow.xaml
<controls:MicaWindow x:Class="BringBackTheOldEdge.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:MicaWPF.Controls;assembly=MicaWPF"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:behaviors="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xaml/behaviors"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:BringBackTheOldEdge"
        xmlns:wv2="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Wpf;assembly=Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Wpf"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        TitleBarType="WinUI"
        SystemBackdropType="Acrylic"
        ChangeTitleColorWhenInactive="False"
        Title=" " Height="450" Width="800" TitleBarHeight="40"
        >
    <controls:MicaWindow.TitleBarContent>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">

            <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center">Edge</TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
    </controls:MicaWindow.TitleBarContent>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="23*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Rectangle   Fill="#55000000" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Margin="0,-81,0,0"/>
        <TabControl x:Name="tabControl1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Background="{x:Null}" SelectionChanged="tabControl1_SelectionChanged">
            <TabItem x:Name="AddTabButton" Header="➕"/>
        </TabControl>
        <Menu x:Name="menu1" Margin="0,2,4,0" Background="{x:Null}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="23" Width="28" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="2" MinWidth="28" MinHeight="24" BorderBrush="#66888888" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1">
            <MenuItem Header="⚙️" Height="20" Width="27" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Regular" HorizontalAlignment="Left" RenderTransformOrigin="0.765,0.502">
                <MenuItem Header="_1" IsCheckable="true" Background="{x:Null}" />
                <MenuItem Header="_2" IsCheckable="true" Background="{x:Null}" />
                <MenuItem Header="_3" IsCheckable="true" Background="{x:Null}" />
            </MenuItem>
        </Menu>
    </Grid>
</controls:MicaWindow>

MainWindow.xaml.cs
using System.Reflection.PortableExecutable;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Windows.Threading;
using MicaWPF.Controls;
using MicaWPF.Core.Services;
using Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core;
using static System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames;
using static System.Runtime.InteropServices.JavaScript.JSType;

namespace BringBackTheOldEdge
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : MicaWindow
    {  
        public int tabnum = 0;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            var converter = new System.Windows.Media.BrushConverter();
            var brush = (Brush)converter.ConvertFromString("#55000000");
            int idx = tabControl1.Items.Count;
            tabControl1.SelectedIndex = idx - 1;
            TabItem ti = new TabItem();
            ti.Header = idx / 2;
            int tabidx = idx - 1;
            RegisterName("tab0", ti);
            tabnum++;
            var ucont = new UserControl1();
            ti.Content = ucont;
            ucont.UpdateName("tab0");
            ti.Background = brush;
            tabControl1.Items.Insert(tabControl1.Items.Count - 1, ti);
            TabItem closeBtn = new TabItem();
            closeBtn.Header = "x";
            closeBtn.Background = brush;
            ti.IsSelected = true;
            tabControl1.Items.Insert(tabControl1.Items.Count - 1, closeBtn);
            tabControl1.SelectedIndex += 1;

        }

        private void tabControl1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            string tabItem = ((sender as TabControl).SelectedItem as TabItem).Header as string;

            switch (tabItem)
            {
                case "➕":
                    var converter = new System.Windows.Media.BrushConverter();
                    var brush = (Brush)converter.ConvertFromString("#55000000");
                    int idx = tabControl1.Items.Count;
                    tabControl1.SelectedIndex = idx - 1;
                    TabItem ti = new TabItem();
                    ti.Header = idx/2;
                    tabnum++;
                    RegisterName("tab" + tabnum.ToString(), ti);
                    var ucont = new UserControl1();
                    ti.Content = ucont;
                    ucont.UpdateName("tab" + tabnum.ToString());
                    ti.Background = brush;
                    TabItem closeBtn = new TabItem();
                    closeBtn.Header = "x";
                    closeBtn.Background = brush;
                    tabControl1.Items.Insert(tabControl1.Items.Count - 1, ti);
                    ti.IsSelected = true;
                    tabControl1.Items.Insert(tabControl1.Items.Count - 1, closeBtn);
                    break;
                case "x":
                    if (tabControl1.Items.Count == 3)
                    {
                        tabControl1.SelectedIndex -= 1;
                        if (MessageBox.Show("Czy chcesz zamknąć przeglądarkę?", "Uwaga", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel, MessageBoxImage.Warning) == MessageBoxResult.OK)
                        {
                            System.Windows.Application.Current.Shutdown();
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                    if (tabControl1.SelectedIndex != 1)
                    {
                        int idx1 = tabControl1.SelectedIndex - 1;
                        tabControl1.Items.RemoveAt(idx1);
                        int idx2 = tabControl1.SelectedIndex;
                        tabControl1.SelectedIndex-=2;
                        tabControl1.Items.RemoveAt(idx2);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        int idx1 = tabControl1.SelectedIndex - 1;
                        tabControl1.Items.RemoveAt(idx1);
                        int idx2 = 0;
                        tabControl1.SelectedIndex += 1;
                        tabControl1.Items.RemoveAt(idx2);
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    return;
            }
        }

        public void UpdateTabName(string text, string tab)
        {
             //here i need to update the tab names
        }
    }

}

BrowserDisplay.xaml
<UserControl x:Class="BringBackTheOldEdge.UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:BringBackTheOldEdge"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <Frame x:Name="viewer"  Source="BrowserPage.xaml"/>
</UserControl>

BrowserDisplay.xaml.cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace BringBackTheOldEdge
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Logika interakcji dla klasy UserControl1.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
    {
        public UserControl1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void UpdateName(string text)
        {
            var page = new Page1() as Page1;
            page.UpdateName(text);
            
        }
    }
}

BrowserPage.xaml
<Page x:Class="BringBackTheOldEdge.Page1"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
      xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:MicaWPF.Controls;assembly=MicaWPF"
      xmlns:wv2="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Wpf;assembly=Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Wpf"
      xmlns:local="clr-namespace:BringBackTheOldEdge"
      mc:Ignorable="d" 
      d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800"
      Title="Page1">
    <Grid>
        <wv2:WebView2 x:Name="webView"
               Source="about:blank" Margin="0,43,0,0" SourceChanged="webView_SourceChanged" NavigationCompleted="webView_NavigationCompleted"
/>
        <controls:TextBox x:Name="textBox1" KeyDown="OnKeyDownHandler" Margin="163,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="#00000000" Watermark="Wyszukaj lub wpisz adres..." Height="37" GotMouseCapture="textBox1_GotMouseCapture" GotKeyboardFocus="textBox1_GotKeyboardFocus"/>
        <controls:Button Content="←" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="37" Width="37" Margin="10,1,0,0" FontSize="10" Background="#00000000" BorderBrush="#00000000" Click="Button_Click"/>
        <controls:Button Content="→" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="37" Width="37" Margin="47,1,0,0" FontSize="10" Background="#00000000" BorderBrush="#00000000" Click="Button_Click_1"/>
        <controls:Button Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="37" Width="37" Margin="84,1,0,0" FontSize="10" Background="#00000000" BorderBrush="#00000000" Click="Button_Click_2"/>
        <controls:Button Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="37" Width="37" Margin="121,1,0,0" FontSize="10" Background="#00000000" BorderBrush="#00000000" Click="Button_Click_3"/>
    </Grid>
</Page>


BrowserPage.xaml.cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using MicaWPF.Core.Services;
using Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core;

namespace BringBackTheOldEdge
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Logika interakcji dla klasy Page1.xaml
    /// </summary>
    /// 
    
    public partial class Page1 : Page
    {
        public static string tabname; // Modifiable


        public Page1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            webView.Source = new System.Uri("https://www.msn.com/spartan/dhp?locale=en-US&market=US&enableregulatorypsm=0&enablecpsm=0&ishostisolationenforced=0&targetexperience=default");
            MicaWPFServiceUtility.AccentColorService.UpdateAccentsColorsFromWindows();
            textBox1.Focus();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            webView.GoBack();
        }

        private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            webView.GoForward();
        }

        private void webView_SourceChanged(object sender, CoreWebView2SourceChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            string strr = webView.Source.ToString();

            if (webView.Source.ToString() == "https://www.msn.com/spartan/dhp?locale=en-US&market=US&enableregulatorypsm=0&enablecpsm=0&ishostisolationenforced=0&targetexperience=default")
            {
                strr = "";
            }
            if (strr.Contains("edge://"))
            {
                textBox1.Text = "❇️Edge | " + StripPrefix(strr, "edge://"); ;
            }
            else
            {
                textBox1.Text = "Wczytywanie | " + StripPrefix(StripPrefix(strr, "https://"), "http://"); ;
            }
            
        }

        private void OnKeyDownHandler(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Key == Key.Return)
            {
                if (textBox1.Text.Contains(':'))
                {
                    webView.Source = new System.Uri(textBox1.Text);
                }
                else
                {
                    webView.Source = new System.Uri("http://" + textBox1.Text);
                }

            }
        }

        public static string StripPrefix(string text, string prefix)
        {
            return text.StartsWith(prefix) ? text.Substring(prefix.Length) : text;
        }

        private void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            webView.Source = new System.Uri("https://www.msn.com/spartan/dhp?locale=en-US&market=US&enableregulatorypsm=0&enablecpsm=0&ishostisolationenforced=0&targetexperience=default");
        }

        private void webView_NavigationCompleted(object sender, CoreWebView2NavigationCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            string strr = webView.Source.ToString();
            if (strr.Contains("https:"))
            {
                strr = "Zabezpieczona | " + strr;
            }
            else
            {
                strr = "⚠️Potencjalnie niebezpieczna | " + strr;
            }
            if (webView.Source.ToString() == "https://www.msn.com/spartan/dhp?locale=en-US&market=US&enableregulatorypsm=0&enablecpsm=0&ishostisolationenforced=0&targetexperience=default")
            {
                strr = "";
            }
            textBox1.Text = StripPrefix(StripPrefix(strr, "https://"), "http://"); ;

            UpdateTab(tabname);
        }

        private void Button_Click_3(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            webView.Reload();
        }

        private void textBox1_GotMouseCapture(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.SelectAll();
        }

        private void textBox1_GotKeyboardFocus(object sender, KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        public void UpdateName(string text)
        {
            tabname = text;
        }

        public void UpdateTab(string text)
        {
            MainWindow mainwindow = ((MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow);
            mainwindow.UpdateTabName(webView.CoreWebView2.DocumentTitle, text);
        }
    }
}



The following may be of interest: How to create Tabs using WebView2 in WPF?

I already made tabs, just the tab titles are broken

I already made tabs: Guess I must have missed them in the code you posted.

I didnt post the full code

Hard to say without seeing the code where are you creating the tabs, but you need to try to access "TabItem.Header" property somehow. And probably header contains TextBlock that can be changed.

Okay, when I have an opportunity, I will share the full code.

Quick Solution:
Improve UpdateTabName
public void UpdateTabName(string text, string tab)
{
    var list = tabControl1.Items.Cast<TabItem>().ToList();
    TabItem tabItem;
    if (tab.Equals("tab0"))
    {
        tabItem = list.Where(p => p.Name.Equals("tab1")).FirstOrDefault();
    }
    else
    {
        tabItem = list.Where(p => p.Name.Equals(tab)).FirstOrDefault();
    }
    tabItem.Header = text;

}

In the tabControl1_SelectionChanged method, add the following code above RegisterName("tab" + tabnum.ToString(), ti);
ti.Name = "tab" + tabnum.ToString();
RegisterName("tab" + tabnum.ToString(), ti);

I found other bugs in your project, you can check it out.
Bug1: Your RegisterName method seems to have no effect
Solution: Use ti.Name = "tab" + tabnum.ToString(); to name
Bug2: The tabControl1_SelectionChanged method was executed when the first TabItem was created, but the name of the TabItem was wrong
Solution: Here I will use conditional judgment to solve your initial problem, and you can improve your logic later
Bug3: There is a delay between TabItem creation and Header update
Solution:
In tabControl1_SelectionChanged
TabItem ti = new TabItem();
ti.Header = idx / 2;

ti.Header can directly give the correct text, so there is no need to execute UpdateTabName
